# Trouble evaluating this integral

Tags: integration, probability-distributions

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty a{|x|}^ke^{-{|x|}^b}dx$$
where $a\in \mathbb{R}$  and $0<b<1$ and $k\in \mathbb{R}$

I am trying to work it towards a gamma function, but the absolute values are putting me off - any help?

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**. One may write, by parity of the integrand,
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty a{|x|}^ke^{-{|x|}^b}dx=2a\int_{0}^\infty {x}^ke^{-{x}^b}dx=\frac{1}{b}\cdot \Gamma \left(\frac{k+1}{b}\right), \quad \tfrac{k+1}{b}>-1,
$$ where we have performed the change of variable $u=x^b$ to get an expression in terms of the Gamma function.